# Error while installing custom logstash gem filter

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I have custom logstash gem filter logstash*******.gem in /opt. But when I try to install it I get following error.

```
Can only install contrib at this time... Exiting.
```

Command which I used to install it: `sudo -u logstash /opt/logstash/bin/plugin install /opt/logstash-filter-XCBXGDNF.gem`
I am using logstash 1.4.2 and RHEL as linux os.

Any advice?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Solved... Installed new version 1.5.2 and it gets resolved.

Comment: Reason (fyi): Logstash's plugin eco system was established with the release of Logstash 1.5.0 Beta 1. https://www.elastic.co/blog/plugin-ecosystem-changes